# Slide ul content with left & right arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have tried an example to slide `UL` content with left and right arrows. I have to show 12 items at a time, when clicking on right arrow next 12 items should be displayed and old items be hide. When clicking on left arrow old 12 items should be displayed and preset 12 items should be hide.

I have tried but i could not complete. Could any one help in completing this example.

[link to my example is here](http://jsbin.com/OqUJUco/1/)

Comment: Why you don't use from jquery plugins? such as [WOW Slider](http://www.wowslider.com/) or [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/)

Comment: [http://jsbin.com/ERUPEGA/1](http://jsbin.com/ERUPEGA/1) on the second for you do $("#entered-names-ul > li:eq("+i+")") and it need to be $("#entered-names-ul > li:eq("+j+")")

Comment: there are an infinite number of sliders around....look through source to see how they do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/MABZj/5/)

Try this, I have created a sample demo for you , you can modify the way you want

```
<div class="move left"><</div>
<div class="move right">></div>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
     <li id="box1" class="box current"><span>avsn9849625263</span></li>
      <li id="box2" class="box"><span>b.venkateshbabu07</span></li>
                  <li id="box3" class="box"><span>baburamesh_2008</span></li>
            <li id="box4" class="box"><span>baburamesh_ch1</span></li>
            <li id="box5" class="box"><span>chrb.rameshbabu</span></li>
            <li id="box6" class="box"><span>chrb.rameshbabu</span></li>
            <li id="box7" class="box"><span>chrb_rameshbabu</span></li>
            <li id="box8" class="box"><span>chrbrameshbabu51</span></li>

    </ul>
 </div>
```

### code

```
var i = 1;
$('.right').click(function () {
    if (i < $("#container ul li").length) {
        $("#box" + i).animate({
            left: '-50%'
        }, 400, function () {
            var $this = $("#box" + i);
            $this.css('left', '150%')
                .appendTo($('.container'));
        });
        $("#box" + i).next().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 400);
        i++;
    }
});
$('.left').click(function () {

    if (i > 1) {
        $("#box" + i).animate({
            left: '150%'
        }, 400, function () {
            var $this = $("#box" + i);
            $this.css('right', '-150%')
                .appendTo($('.container'));
        });
        $("#box" + i).prev().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 400);
        i--;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps, thank you